How can i clear Kotlin-Volley Cache?
I am using volley to send http request to my python api, i send ingredients 'malzemeler' list from android studio and get response recipes 'onerilen_yemekler' but Even though I sent different ingredients lists, the application always prints to textview the result of the first ingredients list. I thought this because of cache and i added some cache clear fun on both android studio and python-flask but i am still getting same response. (It works fine on postman)
Here is my android studio volley code
class FetchYemeklerTask(private val context: Context, private val textView: TextView) {

    fun execute(url: String, malzemeler: List<String>) {
        // Volley kuyruğunu başlat
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

        // Gönderilecek JSON verisini oluştur
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        jsonObject.put("malzemeler", malzemeler)

        // JSON nesnesini POST isteği olarak gönder
        val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                // Yanıtı işle ve TextView'e yaz
                try {
                    val yemeklerArray = response.getJSONArray("onerilen_yemekler")
                    val yemeklerList = mutableListOf<String>()
                    for (i in 0 until yemeklerArray.length()) {
                        yemeklerList.add(yemeklerArray.getString(i))
                    }
                    textView.text = yemeklerList.joinToString("\n")
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                // Hata durumunda ekrana bir mesaj yazdır
                error.printStackTrace()
                textView.text = "Bir hata oluştu: ${error.message}"
            }) {


            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
                return headers
            }
            override fun getCacheKey(): String {
                // Önbelleği devre dışı bırak
                return super.getCacheKey() + "-no-cache"
            }
        }
        // Request'i kuyruğa ekle
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
}

My MainActivty part to call that volley class
        binding.kaydetBut1.setOnClickListener {
            val fetchYemeklerTask = FetchYemeklerTask(this, binding.sonucTV)
            val url = "http://192.168.1.102:5000/oneri-yemekler"
            val malzemeler = listOf("çilek", "yumurta", "şeker","süt")
            fetchYemeklerTask.execute(url, malzemeler)
        }

I have to complete the project today i hope someone can help, thanks

Are you sure you're Python server returns the correct list? Libraries like Volley are not like web browsers, they do not maintain a cache.
